# Requires GLIBCXX_3.4.9 if I've already installed GLIBCXX_4.1.2?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, libstdc++

I'm installing the last version of MediainfoDLL on Fedora 8/9 64bits (http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/es/Download/Fedora).
I downloaded libmediainfo-0.7.20 and libzen0-0.4.3 files.

When I tried to install libzen0 I get this output:

```
# rpm -i libzen0-0.4.3-1.x86_64.Fedora_9.rpm
warning: libzen0-0.4.3-1.x86_64.Fedora_9.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID dfb2ef23
error: Failed dependencies:
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) is needed by libzen0-0.4.3-3.1.x86_64
```

But the problem is that I have already installed the 4.1.2 version of libstdc++:

```
# yum list libstdc++
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * updates-newkey: kdeforge.unl.edu
 * fedora: kdeforge.unl.edu
 * updates: kdeforge.unl.edu
Installed Packages
libstdc++.i386                                                                4.1.2-33                                                               installed
libstdc++.x86_64                                                              4.1.2-33                                                               installed
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Edit:

```
# rpm -q --provides libstdc++
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.1)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.2)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.3)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.4)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.6)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.7)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.8)(64bit)
libstdc++ = 4.1.2-33
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.1)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.2)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.3)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.4)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.6)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.7)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.8)
libstdc++ = 4.1.2-33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly I see a virtually identical output from `rpm -q --provides libstdc++`. I suspect that the *libzen0* RPM you are using has been compiled against a version of libstdc++ which doesn't actually ship on your OS.

Are you installing the correct version of *libzen0* for your OS? If so; try installing the RPM for a similar OS - e.g. the libzen0 for RHEL 5.3?

Answer (score 1):

While I have no experience with 64bit systems it looks like an issue with the rpm: on my system (Fedora 8) I get the following:

```
$ rpm -q --provides libstdc++
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.1)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.2)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.3)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.4)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.6)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.7)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.8)
libstdc++ = 4.1.2-33
```

So if your libstdc++ does not provide `GLIBCXX_3.4.9` like mine I'd consider the rpm broken. One solution would be to create a fake rpm that requires libstdc++ and provides `GLIBCXX_3.4.9`, though the proper solution would be to fix the rpm itself.

Comment: It's exactly the same case, so, how can I create a "fake rpm"?